# pueden explicarme a que se refiere esta linea?

Tags: c++, array

*Utilice una función que reciba un arreglo e imprima sus valores. Se utilizará 3 veces desde el main(), una vez para el arreglo A, otra vez para el arreglo B y otra vez para el arreglo C.*

**Es parte de un problema el cual es este:**

1. Escriba un programa que lea dos arreglos de números enteros ORDENADOS ascendentemente y luego produzca un tercer arreglo ordenado de la mezcla de los dos. Por ejemplo, si los dos arreglos tienen los números 1 3 6 9 17 y 2 4 10 17, respectivamente, el tercer arreglo debe ser 1 2 3 4 6 9 10 17 17.

   - Utilice una función que reciba un arreglo y lea y almacene los datos en él. Se utilizará 2 veces.
   - Utilice una función que reciba los 2 arreglos con datos y el arreglo vacío en donde se hará la mezcla.
   - Utilice una función que reciba un arreglo e imprima sus valores. Se utilizará 3 veces desde el main(), una vez para el arreglo A, otra vez para el arreglo B y otra vez para el arreglo C. Utilice la función para obtener la longitud del arreglo y poder hacer el ciclo for para arreglos de diferentes tamaños.

No se a que se refiere esa linea, solo me falta eso y que los datos aparezcan ordenados.

**Esto es lo que llevo programado:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int LA1,LA2,DP;
    int A1[]={100,99,88,77,66,55,44,33,22,11};
    int A2[]={90,89,78,67,56,45,34,23,12,01};
    int A3[20];

    //declaracion de tamaño del array
    int la1= sizeof(A1);
    int la2= sizeof(A2);
    DP=sizeof(int);
    LA1=la1/DP;
    LA2=la2/DP;
    //copia de valores en array3
    for(int i=0;i<LA1;i++){
        A3[i]=A1[i];
    }
    
    for(int i=10;i<20;i++){
        A3[i]=A2[i-10];
    }
    //Lectura del array 3
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        cout<<A3[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Intuyo que quieren que crees una función que sea llamada desde `main()` la cual haga lo que tengas que hacer. Una posible vía sería almacenar en `A3[]` todos los valores que tienes de los otros dos arrays, y una vez que los tengas en el array final que emplees el método de la burbuja. Es un método lento pero eficaz, y que hay 392053 tutoriales de cómo implementarlo en internet

Comment: La línea en cuestión por la que preguntas es bastante clara en mi opinión. Tienes que escribir una función que reciba como parámetro un array, y que lo imprima por pantalla. Eso es todo. Desde el programa principal llamarás a esa función pasándole como parámetro `A` para que muestre el array A, y después la llamas otra vez pasándole `B` para que muestre el array B, y finalmente el C. Lo de ordenar los arrays es otro tema y esa línea por la que preguntas no dice nada de ordenar arrays. Los arrays que le pases han de estar ya ordenados. En concreto A y B ya lo están porque así deben introducirse

Comment: Por cierto que lo que llevas programado no tiene mucho que ver con lo que te están pidiendo. Te piden que escribas una función para leer los arrays. Eso no lo tienes, y de hecho los arrays los estás poniendo con valores prefijados desde el código fuente, en lugar de pedirlos al usuario. Te dicen que los datos que meta el usuario han de venir ya ordenados (por tanto no tienes que ordenar A ni B, ya vienen ordenados). Pero tienes que crear C que sea mezcla ordenada de A y B, es decir, hacer un _merge sort_. Tampoco tienes hecho eso.

Comment: En cambio haces otras cosas que no sé qué pintan, como copiar un array en otro pero restando 10 al índice, calcular `LA1` y `LA2` (y el segundo no se usa), imprimir A3 por pantalla (aunque el comentario dice que lo estás leyendo, lo estás imprimiendo), etc... La impresión que tengo es que el código que adjuntas lo has copiado de otra parte, sin entender si se relaciona o no con lo que te piden (y no se relaciona)

Comment: @Londo gracias por el consejo, checaré ese método que mencionas.

Comment: @abulafia Gracias por los consejos tan detallados, confundí las instrucciones dado que nunca había visto lo que es una función, tomaré en cuenta tus consejos ya he revisado y ahora le hallo algo más de sentido a las instrucciones.